# Save Related Model Data

Tags: php, cakephp

I am having trouble understanding how to save Related Model Data in Cakephp 1.3. I have a model called Policy and a Model called Declinations. Policy hasMany Declinations. Declinations belongsTo Policy. All I want to do is save the policy_id in the Policy table in a field called policy_id in the Declinations table. So the question is how do I grab the Policy_Id from the corresponding model? Do I need to set the Policy_Id first in the Declination model or controller and then pass it to a hidden field in the view?

Here is my declination model

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Policy' => array(
        'className' => 'Policy',
        'foreignKey' => 'policy_id'
```

My Policy Model is as follows

```
public $hasMany = array(
             'Declination' => array(
        'className' => 'Declination',
        'foreignKey' => 'policy_id',
        'dependent' => true
    )
```

Here is my controller

```
public function add($id = null) {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Declination->create();
        if ($this->Declination->saveAll($this->data['Declination'])) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Declinations saved.', true));
            $this->redirect(array(
                'controller' => 'coverages',
                'action' => 'view',
                $id
            ));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Declinations failed to save.', true));
        }
    }
    $reasons = $this->Declination->Reason->find('list');
    $contactTypes = $this->Declination->ContactType->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('id', 'reasons', 'contactTypes'));
}
```

Here is my view

```
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.first_name"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.last_name"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.company"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.contact_type_id"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.phone_number"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.reason_id"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.other", array(
            'label' => 'If other, please supply a reason'
        )); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.dated", array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'readonly' => 'readonly',
            'data-datepicker' => ''
        )); ?>
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, you must know WHICH Policy id you want to save - so you can either add that as a field in your view:

```
echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.policy_id", array('value'=>$policyId));
```

Or you can set it in your Controller before you save:

```
$this->request->data['Declination']['policy_id'] = $policyId;
```

Either way will work - use whichever makes more sense for your site.

How and where you GET the policy id is also up to you.  You can use a `find()` in the Controller, then `set()` it so it's accessible in the view.  Or, you can use a `find()` and retrieve it just before the save.  Without knowing what data you have available where, it's hard to give more detail than that.

Comment: If this answered your question (regardless of if you came to the same conclusion), I would suggest marking it as such (the checkmark), so other people don't waste their time trying to help you if it's already solved :)

Comment: Yea, shortly after I posted this question I added this to my view....<?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.policy_id", array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => '$policy_id')); ?>....Now the only thing I have to do is call the find method in my controller and then send it to the view. The only thing is Im not too sure how to execute it. Now being that Im in my Declinations controller how would I access the data in the Parent Model? I know that associations are defined one way. How would I access the data in the other direction? I tried $this->Declination->Policy but it doesn't work.

Comment: That's a very common question found throughout stackoverflow as well as via Google.

Comment: I did this in order to access the parent model. $this->loadmodel('Policy')........$policy_id = $this->Policy->find('all');.......Now all my data is populating in an array.